# display child posts based on category terms

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a custom post type named **city guide** . The child post articles are displayed within the parent page.Child posts has custom category named as newyork and paris.

```
<div class="container">
<?php while( have_posts() ): the_post();  ?>
<div class="row main-content-wrap">
  <div class="col-md-12 long-post-sections-wrapper">
<?php while( $city_guide->have_posts() ): $city_guide->the_post(); 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'city-guide-cities-category' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;

} }
 ?> 

<div <?php post_class('city-guide-row row' . classes_related($wp_query->current_post) ); ?>>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h3 id="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post()->post_name ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="img-caption"><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?></div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 map-container">

        <!-- google map -->
        <div class="map-wrapper">
            <div class="mobile-map-overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div>
            <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"width="100%" height="260" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=<?php echo get_field('address',get_the_ID()); ?>&ie=UTF8&t=roadmap&z=6&iwloc=B&output=embed&z=16"></iframe>
        </div>

        <h5>Address</h5>
        <?php echo get_field('address'); ?><br/>
        <?php echo get_field('address_2'); ?>

        <h5>Contact</h5>
        <?php if(get_field('contact_number')): 
            echo '<a href="tel:' . get_field('contact_number') . '">' . get_field('contact_number') . '</a>';
        endif; ?><br/>
        <?php if(get_field('website')): 
            echo '<a href="' . get_field('website') . '" target="_blank">' . get_field('website') . '</a>';
        endif; ?><br/>
        <?php if(get_field('email')): 
            echo '<a href="mailto:' . get_field('email') . '">' . get_field('email') . '</a>';
        endif; ?>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr class="city-row-separator"/>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have printed **print $term->name ;** inside while so each child article is showing its own categories.

What i want to achieve is display **newyork** posts first and then **paris**.

```
if ( $term->name == 'newyork'){

}
elseif ( $term->name == 'paris'){

}
```

did not result what i expected.how can I achieve ?Please help

Edit:

tried this returnd nothing.

```
 <?php 
foreach ($NY_array as $key => $value) {
$args = array(
'post__in' => $NY_Posts,
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts as $p) : ?>
<div <?php post_class('city-guide-row row' . classes_related($wp_query->current_post) ); ?>>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h3 id="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post()->post_name ); ?>"><?php $p->post_title; ?></h3>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="img-caption"><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?></div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 map-container">

        <!-- google map -->
        <div class="map-wrapper">
            <div class="mobile-map-overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div>
            <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"width="100%" height="260" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=<?php echo get_field('address',get_the_ID()); ?>&ie=UTF8&t=roadmap&z=6&iwloc=B&output=embed&z=16"></iframe>
        </div>

        <h5>Address</h5>
        <?php echo get_field('address'); ?><br/>
        <?php echo get_field('address_2'); ?>

        <h5>Contact</h5>
        <?php if(get_field('contact_number')): 
            echo '<a href="tel:' . get_field('contact_number') . '">' . get_field('contact_number') . '</a>';
        endif; ?><br/>
        <?php if(get_field('website')): 
            echo '<a href="' . get_field('website') . '" target="_blank">' . get_field('website') . '</a>';
        endif; ?><br/>
        <?php if(get_field('email')): 
            echo '<a href="mailto:' . get_field('email') . '">' . get_field('email') . '</a>';
        endif; ?>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/shop-the-story-city-guide', 'single'   );  ?>
</div>
<hr class="city-row-separator"/>
<?php 
endforeach;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guide you  through simple code as per your current code

> though It is not the standard solution , but can complete the
>   requirement

Run the loop and collect the posts in NewYork and Paris in separate array as `$NY_array` and `$PA_array`
and their Posts Ids also in separate arrays `$NY_Posts` and `$PA_Posts`

> Edit starts

```
 <?php 
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'city-guide-cities-category' );
         // Loop over each item since it's an array
        if ( $terms != null ){
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( $term->name == 'newyork'){
                    $NY_array[] = array('term_id'=> $term->term_taxonomy_id, 'count' => $term->count);
                    $NY_Posts[] = $post->ID;
                } 
                elseif ( $term->name == 'paris'){
                    $PA_array[] = array('term_id'=> $term->term_taxonomy_id, 'count' => $term->count);
                    $PA_Posts[] = $post->ID;
                }
            }
        }
    endwhile; ?>
```

> Edit Ends

Now run the 2 separate loops first for Newyork and then for Paris

```
<?php 
foreach ($NY_array as $key => $value) {
    $args = array(
    'post__in' => $NY_Posts,
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts as $p) :
        //do the code here 
        //below code replaced by 
            //$p->post_title;
            //$p->post_excerpt
            //get_field('address',$p->ID); 
            //get_field('address_2',$p->ID); 
            //get_field('contact_number',$p->ID); and so on 
            // try to print print_r($p) if you need to print some data from Post like content, title, featured image etc
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Similarly for the PA_array

```
<?php foreach ($PA_array as $key => $value) {
    $args = array(
    'post__in' => $PA_Posts,
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts as $p) :
        //do the code here 
        //below code replaced by 
            //$p->post_title;
            //$p->post_excerpt
            //get_field('address',$p->ID); 
            //get_field('address_2',$p->ID); 
            //get_field('contact_number',$p->ID); and so on 
            // try to print print_r($p) if you need to print some data from Post like content, title, featured image etc
    endforeach;
}?>
```

Comment: can you please let me know which part is not understood , so tha I can edit that

Comment: <h3 id="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post()->post_name ); ?>"><?php echo $p->post_title; ?></h3> this gave me helloworld as title

Comment: can you please try to `print_r($NY_Posts,)` above `foreach($NY_array as $key => $value) {}` and let me know the output

Comment: Okay got that .. please correct `if ( $term->name == 'newyork'){
                $NY_array[] = array('term_id'=> $term->term_taxonomy_id, 'count' => $term->count);
                $NY_Posts[] = $post->ID;
            } 
            elseif ( $term->name == 'paris'){
                $PA_array[] = array('term_id'=> $term->term_taxonomy_id, 'count' => $term->count);
                $PA_Posts[] = $post->ID;
            }`

OR see the edited answer ...first block of code has been edited

Comment: the main is goal is to separte to child posts based on my two categories and dispaly in a tab which i can take care of

Comment: run all new york first then paris .. will if statement helps.above seems broken

Comment: In your question you have to while loops `<?php while( have_posts() ): the_post();  ?>` and 
`<?php while( $city_guide->have_posts() ): $city_guide->the_post();?> ` which one is getting all the posts and post IDs ? Try using that while loop in my answer

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105004/discussion-between-prakash-rao-and-melvin).